Azure Pipeline CI: Cache@2 docker cache is not picking up the cache
Here's the sample release pipeline:
stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and push stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DOCKER_BUILDKIT]1"
            displayName: Enable Docker BuildKit

          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Login to container registry
            inputs:
              command: login
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)

          - script: |
              mkdir -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache
              echo "Contents of cache directory before build:"
              ls -la $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache
            displayName: Ensure Docker cache directory exists

          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Build and Push Docker Image to ACR
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                echo "Create new builder with docker-container driver..."
                docker buildx create --name builder --driver docker-container --bootstrap --use

                echo "Build image using the new builder..."
                docker buildx build --builder builder \
                  --cache-from=type=local,src=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache \
                  --cache-to=type=local,dest=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache,mode=max \
                  --tag $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(releaseTag) \
                  --tag $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(latestTag) \
                  --file $(dockerfilePath) \
                  $(buildContext) \
                  --push

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Save Docker layers cache
            inputs:
              key: $(cacheKey)
              path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache

          - script: |
              echo "Contents of cache directory after build:"
              ls -la $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache
              docker images
            displayName: List Docker Images and Cache Contents

          - script: |
              echo "Cache hit/miss info:"
              echo "Cache key: $(cacheKey)"
            displayName: Log cache information

but unfortunately it's still not working
EDIT 3

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and push stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Login to container registry
            inputs:
              command: login
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache Docker image
            inputs:
              key: $(cacheKey)
              path: $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)
              cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED

          - script: |
              echo "Checking for Docker cache directory..."
              if [ -d "$(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)" ]; then
                echo "Cache directory exists. Listing contents..."
                ls -la $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)
                if [ -f "$(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)/cache.tar" ]; then
                  echo "Cache file exists. Loading Docker cache..."
                  docker load -i $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)/cache.tar || echo "Failed to load cache"
                else
                  echo "Cache file does not exist."
                fi
              else
                echo "Cache directory does not exist. Skipping cache load."
              fi
            displayName: Load Docker cache if directory exists
            condition: eq(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')

          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build and Push Docker Image to ACR
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              command: buildAndPush
              Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
              buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/services/api
              tags: |
                $(releaseTag)
                $(latestTag)

          - script: |
              echo "Saving Docker image to cache..."
              mkdir -p $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)
              IMAGE_TAG=$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(releaseTag)
              if docker image inspect $IMAGE_TAG > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                docker save -o $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)/cache.tar $IMAGE_TAG
                echo "Docker image saved to cache."
              else
                echo "Image $IMAGE_TAG not found. Skipping cache save."
              fi
            displayName: Cache docker layers

          - script: |
              echo "Contents of cache directory after build:"
              ls -la $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)
              docker images
              echo "Cache hit/miss info:"
              echo "Cache key: $(cacheKey)"
            displayName: List Docker Images and Cache Contents

Based on the EDIT 3, the cache hit is happening, it loads the cache and saves the cache as well. but somehow it doesn't still use the cached layer while docker build, it's installing all the packages again everytime.
Few things tried,

Initially tried with cache@2 & docker@2 tasks. it wasn't working
Manually mkdir a cache folder
Manually pull the previous docker image from ACR locally for docker-cache to pick up.
Finally this version, it seems to be working partially. one thing is, the build time has significantly increased after this step.

worst case option I do have is to use self-hosted vm agent for the docker build but is it advisable to use in production?
there's something that this script is missing would be great, if we're able to figure the missing part.
happy to provide more information.
& keep this thread open here for future reference if this may help someone. I'll add my findings here as we proceed :)

In the pipeline YAML you provided, you did not specify the directory of the local Docker cache on the Docker build task.
When building Docker image, if you want to use the Docker cache from a local directory, you should use the options "--cache-to" and "--cache-from" to specify the local directory. See "Local cache".
docker buildx build --push -t <registry>/<image> \
  --cache-to type=local,dest=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache \
  --cache-from type=local,src=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache .

When you build the Docker image in pipeline in the first time, you can:

Use the option "--cache-to type=local,dest=path/to/local/dir" on the build command to export the build cache as files to the specified local directory.
Use the Cache@2 task to save the cache from the specified local directory.

In the subsequent times when you build images in pipeline, you can:

Use the Cache@2 task restore the previous cache into a specified local directory.
Use the option "--cache-from type=local,src=path/to/local/dir" on the build command to import the cache from the specified local directory.
Use the option "--cache-to type=local,dest=path/to/local/dir" on the build command to export the new build cache as files to the specified local directory.
Use the Cache@2 task to save the new cache from the specified local directory.


EDIT:
The docker@2 task is calling the "docker build" command with the default docker driver.

For "--cache-from" option, the docker driver currently only supports importing build cache from the registry.
For "--cache-to" option, the docker driver only supports cache exports using the inline and local cache backends.

For your case, instead of using the docker@2 task, I recommend you try use a script task (such as Bash@3) to run the "docker buildx build" command with the docker-container driver. See below sample as reference.
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  . . .

  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: 'Login to ACR'
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: DockerRegistryServiceConnection
      command: login

  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Restore cache'
    . . .

  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Build and Push image'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "Create new builder with docker-container driver..."
        docker buildx create --name mybuilder --driver docker-container --bootstrap --use

        echo "Build image using the new builder..."
        docker buildx build --builder mybuilder \
          --cache-to type=local,dest=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache \
          --cache-from type=local,src=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache \
          -t <registry>/<image> --push -f Dockerfile .

  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Save new cache'
    . . .


EDIT_2:
I attempted with below sample referencing the documentation "Reduce build time using caching", and it can work fine.
variables:
  repository: 'xxxx'
  key: 'xxxx'
  DOCKER_CACHE_DIR: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: build
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Cache Docker image'
    inputs:
      key: '$(key)'
      path: '$(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)'
      cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'
  
  - script: docker load -i $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)/cache.tar
    displayName: 'Load restored image'
    condition: eq(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
  
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: 'Build and Push image'
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'xxxx'
      repository: '$(repository)'
      command: 'buildAndPush'
      Dockerfile: 'path/to/Dockerfile'
      tags: |
        $(Build.BuildId)
        latest
  
  - script: |
      mkdir -p $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)
      docker save -o $(DOCKER_CACHE_DIR)/cache.tar $(repository):$(Build.BuildId)
    displayName: 'Save new image'

Description

After using above configurations, when running the pipeline at the first time:

The Cache@2 task gets a cache miss as not cache can be found to restore. This is expected.
The "docker load" step gets skipped as no image to load from the specified cache directory (DOCKER_CACHE_DIR).
The Docker@2 task goes to build a new image (repository:tag).
The "docker save" step saves the specified image (repository:tag) as tar archive file (cache.tar) into the specified cache directory (DOCKER_CACHE_DIR).
At the end of the job, it will automatically generate a Post cache task (Post-job: Cache Docker image) to upload the tar archive file (cache.tar) as a cache from the specified cache directory (DOCKER_CACHE_DIR).


When running the pipeline at the second time and the subsequent times, you do not need to make any changes in the pipeline:

The Cache@2 task gets a cache hit if any cache can be hit with the specified key. The most recently created cache will be restored into the specified cache directory (DOCKER_CACHE_DIR). The value of the cache hit variable 'CACHE_RESTORED' is set to 'true'.
The "docker load" step gets run to load the image from the restored cache (cache.tar).
When the Docker@2 task to build a new image, "docker build" will automatically work with the cache of the same image loaded previously.
The "docker save" step saves the new image as tar archive file (cache.tar) into the specified cache directory (DOCKER_CACHE_DIR). I will overwrite the old file.
The Post cache task upload the new tar archive file as a new cache.





still it's not working, here's the updated
in docker@2,
buildContext: $(buildContext)
arguments: |
--cache-from=type=local,src=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache
--cache-to=type=local,dest=$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.docker/cache,mode=max
--build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1

@Navemics, I have updated my above answer with more information and suggestion (See EDIT). Check and try with it.

Thanks for your edit, I've also tried this way but it still doesn't work, i've posted my. current script in the edited question, (see EDIT). i think i'm missing out something small, but could figure it out.

@Navemics, From the new YAML you posted, I do not see you have a Cache@2 task to save the new cache from the local path. As I suggested above, in the first time, you need to use a Cache@2 task after the build task to save the build cache. Then in the subsequent times, you can use a Cache@2 task before the build task to restore the previous cache for use, and use a Cache@2 task after the build task to save the new build cache.

Thanks for your response, I've tried as you said, and updated the EDIT as well, but it's not working as expected still. I've added the Cache@2 task to save & retrieve cache, when saving it mentioned logs that the file is uploading, also when retrieving the second time, it mentioned there's 8 files, which didn't change previously too. your help is much appreciated

@Navemics, Can you provided the detailed debugging logs of the steps? Maybe, we can find some things from the debugging logs for further troubleshooting.

Thanks for your response, I've added the detailed logs there, seems to be that it couldn't find the cache in the directory.

@Navemics, From the YAML you updated above, I did not see you followed my suggestion that using the docker-container driver to run the "docker buildx build".

Sorry it was not updated, I've updated it now. but still with that. it's not working :(
btw, thanks for all your efforts on still helping out

@Navemics, Okay, I will try to investigate it further.

@Navemics, Reference the steps shared under EDIT_2 in my answer to configure your pipeline.

I've updated my question with EDIT 3, based on. your suggestions. somehow the cache is being saved & cache hit is happening. but still it's not using cache while building image.

@Navemics, View the Docker docs "Cache invalidation". Here stated that the cache might not be invalidated for certain instructions.

I don't think there's any issue with the dockerfile, as caches works fine in the vm directly when built in it. could it be because of anything else?
